# Get list of objects only when hasMany relations has element

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have 3 tables

```
Shops    - id, place_id, name...
Products - id, shop_id, name ...
Product_Tag - product_id, tag_id ... (pivot table)
Tags - id....
```

And I would like to get results in array like this:

```
array [
  0 => [
    "id" => 1,
    "name" => "Shop name",
    "products" => [...]
  ]
]
```

but I would like to search it by place_id and tag name. Something like this:

```
$shops = Shop::where('place_id', 1)
     ->with(array('products' => function($query)
     {
        $query->whereHas('tags', function ($query) {
            $query->where('slug', 'tagname1');
        });
     }))->get();
```

This is working okay. But if none of shop products has that tag, I would still get Shop object with empty products array. Everything is okay if in that shop, at least one product has that tag. I don't want to get shop if it has empty products list. Also I think it's overhead to foreach that array and search for empty arrays and then to remove shop object. Is there better way to don't fetch from database at all ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest your 'has' statements. See: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#querying-relations

So this should work:

```
$shops = Shop::where('place_id', 1)->whereHas('products.tags', function ($query) {
    $query->where('slug', 'tagname1');
 })->with(products.tags)->get();
```